# nodejs worker_threads How to understand that all workers have completed work

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker

Began to study worker_threads in nodejs 
After completion of work, the last worker must finish the script
process.exit();

my index.js

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const logUpdate = require("log-update");
const threads = 100;
const someData = 'some data';

let names = [...Array(threads)].fill(0);
for (let i = 0; i < threads; i++) {

    const port = new Worker(require.resolve("./worker.js"), {
        workerData: { someData, i }
    });

    port.on("message", (data) => handleMessage(data, i));
    port.on("error", (e) => console.log(e));
    port.on("exit", (code) => console.log(`Exit code: ${code}`));
}

function handleMessage(_, index) {
    names[index]++;
    logUpdate(names.map((status, i) => `Thread ${i}: ${status}  ${_}`).join("\n"));
}
```

worker.js

```
const { parentPort, workerData } = require("worker_threads" )
const { someData, i } = workerData;

(async () => {
    parentPort.postMessage( `worker start ${i} some data ${someData}`);
    process.exit();
})();
```

Now workers are created and work out, but after they are completed, the script does not complete its work

Answer (score 0):

From whatever knowledge I have, I understand that if there is no error caused in the worker until its exit, then the return code is 0, otherwise 1 (automatically). Look at [process exit codes](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

So when you do `process.exit()` at that time you can pass the code as an argument. (or not have `process.exit()` at all).

Generally what I have seen, and do is:

1. Wrap the worker creation in a Promise returning function. 
   **NOTE:**

   - worker.terminate() : terminates the worker thread.
   - (Personal choice) I choose to do `parentPort.postMessage(JSON.stringify(true))` if I complete my task
     in my worker thread. Hence 
      `worker.on('message', message => {if (message === true) {worker.terminate();resolve(true);} else {console.log(message)}});`
      in the main thread.
2. Whenever I have to create threads for repetitive task-delegations. I use .map function on the array. the function inside returns the same return value as that from my worker creator (Promised returning) function. Hence eventually I map the array into array of promises.
3. Then I put this array of promises into Promise.all().
4. Then I check for returned values of Promise.all()

Checkout:

1. [My Gist](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/Omkaragrawal/1a172a0172412af3b264032a15581c2e.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) (as an example for `Promise.all()`).
2. [Medium](https://medium.com/lazy-engineering/node-worker-threads-b57a32d84845) (Just for worker_thread basics. An Awesome article)